# Disable exporting data from the user interface

Tags: kentico

Can we disable exporting data from the user interface actions in Kentico Managing form data?

Regards,
SA

Comment: What data? Or just anything?

Comment: I think they are referring to the context menu export of data into xsl/xml files on any unigrid

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `ShowObjectMenu` property of the UniGrid to `false`. Detailed documentation available [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/references/kentico-controls/ui-controls/unigrid/reference-unigrid-definition).

The UniGrid definition should be the one found in this file (can't verify it as I currently don't have access to a Kentico instance): `CMSModules\BizForms\Controls\BizFormEditData.ascx`

Answer (score 0):

Not all objects, pages, etc have the permissions available/coded to allow this restriction that I'm aware of within the user interface.  Take a [look at the post I wrote](https://www.kehrendev.com/blog/brenden-kehren/may-2015/secure-your-kentico-site,-content-and-objects-from) on restricting download/export of anything out of Kentico.

Short story is you set the permissions at the IIS level on `/CMS/CMSSiteUtils/Export` directory to not allow the user running IIS app pool to access that directory.  This directory is where all exports, no matter what, get sent to.